# Python Changing module variables in another module

Tags: python, module

Say I am importing the module 'foo' into the module 'bar'.
Is it possible for me to change a global variable in foo inside bar?

Let the global variable in foo be 'arbit'.
Change arbit so that if bar were to call a function of foo that uses this variable, the updated variable is used rather than the one before that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
import foo
foo.arbit = 'new value'
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Had tried it but there was some other error in the program so thought there might be some catch.